# Combining date and time fields in ETL SQL Query

Tags: sql, datetime, business-objects

I have multiple date and time fields that I need to combine into a datetime in a SQL Query.  I unfortunately cannot change the initial database structure to combine them in the original server.
I can combine the SQL Query data after export, but because of the problem of flat files conversion, and the possibility of data corruption/loss, I am hesitant as I would need to convert the flat file twice.

These are the things I've tried:

```
    SELECT Combine = cast([DateValue] as datetime) + Cast([TimeValue] as datetime)
```

Unfortunately, this leads to errors where I have fewer columns than original fields....

The original Query looks like this:

```
    SELECT 
      Ordered_Date.DateValue, 
      Ordered_TOD.TimeValue, 
      Start_Date.DateValue, 
      Start_TOD.TimeValue, 
      End_Date.DateValue, 
      End_TOD.TimeValue, 
    Discontinued_Date.DateValue, 
    Discontinued_TOD.TimeValue 

    FROM 
       warehouse_report........... 

    WHERE 
        ( ..... )
```

If I add The Combine command into the SQL query, it seems to working in that it is combining the date/time.  The issue is that when I implement this in the SELECT section of the SQL Query, I have 1 less column and it won't let me execute the script...

```
    SELECT 
      Ordered_Date.DateValue, 
      Ordered_TOD.TimeValue, 
      Start_Date.DateValue, 
      Start_TOD.TimeValue, 
      COMBINE = CAST(End_Date.DateValue as datetime) + CAST(End_TOD.TimeValue as datetime), 
      Discontinued_Date.DateValue, 
      Discontinued_TOD.TimeValue 

    FROM 
       warehouse_report........... 

    WHERE 
        ( ..... )
```

This gives me one less column on the output of the SQL Query...

Comment: Please provide which DBMS you are using.

Comment: I believe that the Business Object DBMS is a SQL server.  I tried scripting it for an Oracle server and it gives me syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about concatenate the values and parse:

`SELECT cast([DateValue]||' '||[TimeValue] as datetime)`

Please, provide the information about which SGBD you are using to get a better answer.

Edit1:

To SQL Server:

```
Select
    x.d1
From (
    Select 
        convert(datetime, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.0', 121) d1
) x
Union All
Select
    convert(datetime,
        substring(convert(varchar, x.d1, 121), 1, 11)
        + substring(convert(varchar, x.t1, 121), 11, 13)
    , 121)
From (
    Select 
        convert(datetime, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.0', 121) d1,
        convert(datetime, '10:00:22') t1
) x
```

Comment: This gives an "incorrect syntax near '|'.  (Microsoft)(ODBC SQL Server Driver)(SQL Server)

Comment: So try `SELECT convert(datetime, [DateValue] + ' ' + [TimeValue], 121)`. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: It gives me an error "The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the ADD operator"

Comment: The Combine command seems to working in that it is combining the date/time.  The issue is that when I implement this in the SELECT section of the SQL Query, I have 1 less column and it won't let me execute the script

Comment: There is no UNION or UNION ALL capsule.  There are multiple JOINs (inner and outer).